# Como mudar um atributo de uma tag no HTML usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, placeholder

Estou tentando fazer uma ToDoList, e nela quero que cada vez que uma div nova (card para uma nova tarefa) seja adicionada, o placeholder da tag input do título, seja mudado.
Exemplo:

1ª click: placeholder = 'Meta 1'
1ª click: placeholder = 'Meta 2'...

Não consegui colocar uma variável dentro do innerHTML

```
 //Gets
const adTrab = document.getElementById('maisTrabalho')
const linha = document.querySelector('.card_linhas')


//Chamadas

adTrab.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    const cardNovo = document.createElement("div"); // Cria um novo elemento <>
    cardNovo.className = "card_ad"; // Define o atributo de identificação HTML

    cardNovo.innerHTML = "\
    <input id='card_ad__titulo' class='card_ad__titulo' type='text' placeholder='Meta 1'>\
    <label for='meta'>O que você vai fazer?</label>\
    <textarea class='card_ad__inputs' id='meta' type='text' rows='4' cols='10' placeholder='Irei...'></textarea>\
    <label for='tempo'>Qual o prazo?</label>\
    <input class='card_ad__tempo' type='date' name='' id=''>\
    "

})
```

Comment: Faça um [mcve] que dou uma resposta util. Também faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -2):

Não faria dessa forma, mas seguindo o seu código segue um exemplo abaixo:

```html
<div id="addTarefa">Adicionar Tarefa</div>
<div id="conteudo"></div>
<script>
 //Gets
const adTrab = document.getElementById('addTarefa');
const cardNovo = document.getElementById('conteudo');
let num = 0;
adTrab.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    num++;
    cardNovo.innerHTML += "\
    <div><input id='card_ad__titulo' class='card_ad__titulo' type='text' placeholder='Meta "+num+"'>\
    <label for='meta'>O que você vai fazer?</label>\
    <textarea class='card_ad__inputs' id='meta' type='text' rows='4' cols='10' placeholder='Irei...'></textarea>\
    <label for='tempo'>Qual o prazo?</label>\
    <input class='card_ad__tempo' type='date' name='' id=''></div>\
    "

})
</script>
```

Faria desta forma:

```js
var tarefas = [];
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  // adicionar div com conteudo da tarefa
  var tarefa = document.querySelector('#tarefa').value;
  tarefas.push(tarefa);
  // colocar tarefas dentro de uma div
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = "<div class='tarefaList' id='div" + (tarefas.length) + "'>" + tarefa + " <button class='btnApagar' onclick='apagar(this.id)' id='" + (tarefas.length) + "'>X</button></div>";
  document.querySelector('body').appendChild(div);
  console.log(tarefas);
});

function apagar(id) {
  console.log(id);
  document.querySelector('#div' + id).remove();
  tarefas.splice(id, 1);
  console.log(tarefas);
}
```

```css
.tarefa {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.btn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.tarefaList {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btnApagar {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="tarefa" name="tarefa" id="tarefa" placeholder="Digite sua tarefa">
<div class="btn">Adicionar</div>
```

Comment: Legal cara, eu tentei fazer esse +num+ mas não tava funcionando, acho que me confundi com as aspas. 

Tu disse que  não faria desse jeito, tu podes dizer qual seria a solução pra você? Grato pela ajuda!